# facebook publish story error

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am using following code to publish story on facebook:

```
     FacebookWebClient facebookWebClient = new FacebookWebClient(UserSession.CurrentFacebookProfileAccessToken);
 string URL="https://graph.facebook.com/me/tsstesting:start";
  var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
          parameters["og:type"] = "tsstesting:myurl";
          parameters["urlname"] = "http://on.fb.me/12rMxhV";
          parameters["title"] = "QBSTab";
 try
            {
                dynamic result = facebookWebClient.Post(URL, parameters); // again here should be your app name instead of "myapp"
                JObject friendListJson = JObject.Parse(result.ToString());
                string returval = friendListJson["id"].ToString();
                return returval;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
```

It gives me exception  **Object at URL 'https://www.facebook.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'www' for property 'og:locale:alternate' could not be parsed as type 'enum'.**

What I am missing here?